# Traversing XML Schemas failed

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, xsd

I want to parse all information/elements from a xml schema (xsd) and working with them as variables in my program. I found this article from microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255932.aspx

**Code example from Microsoft**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

class XmlSchemaTraverseExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Add the customer schema to a new XmlSchemaSet and compile it. 
        // Any schema validation warnings and errors encountered reading or  
        // compiling the schema are handled by the ValidationEventHandler delegate.
        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallback);
        schemaSet.Add("http://www.tempuri.org", "customer.xsd");
        schemaSet.Compile();

        // Retrieve the compiled XmlSchema object from the XmlSchemaSet 
        // by iterating over the Schemas property.
        XmlSchema customerSchema = null;
        foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas())
        {
            customerSchema = schema;
        }

        // Iterate over each XmlSchemaElement in the Values collection 
        // of the Elements property. 
        foreach (XmlSchemaElement element in customerSchema.Elements.Values)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Element: {0}", element.Name);

            // Get the complex type of the Customer element.
            XmlSchemaComplexType complexType = element.ElementSchemaType as XmlSchemaComplexType;

            // If the complex type has any attributes, get an enumerator  
            // and write each attribute name to the console. 
            if (complexType.AttributeUses.Count > 0)
            {
                IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator =
                    complexType.AttributeUses.GetEnumerator();

                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    XmlSchemaAttribute attribute =
                        (XmlSchemaAttribute)enumerator.Value;

                    Console.WriteLine("Attribute: {0}", attribute.Name);
                }
            }

            // Get the sequence particle of the complex type.
            XmlSchemaSequence sequence = complexType.ContentTypeParticle as XmlSchemaSequence;

            // Iterate over each XmlSchemaElement in the Items collection. 
            foreach (XmlSchemaElement childElement in sequence.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element: {0}", childElement.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    static void ValidationCallback(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            Console.Write("WARNING: ");
        else if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
            Console.Write("ERROR: ");

        Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
    }
}
```

**XML Schema:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="network" type="netType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="netType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Version">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Min" type="xs:int"/>
                        <xs:element name="Max" type="xs:int"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="File">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Min" type="xs:int"/>
                        <xs:element name="Max" type="xs:int"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="NW">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Ethernet">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="Cons">
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:list itemType="xs:int"/>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Mail"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

The program runs without errors, but I get only the elements in the first tree. Example:

**Output:**

```
Element: Version
Element: File
```

But I want all elements: Min, Max from Version and Min, Max from File like:

**What I need:**

```
Element: Version
Element: Min
Element: Max
Element: File
Element: Min
Element: Max
```

**So my questions:**

- How can I get all elements?
- And can I use the elements in my program like: Version.Min = 5.4

Comment: It is going to be very difficult to diagnose what your code is or is not doing without seeing the code!

Comment: Oh sorry I will change it, but I'm using the code example from the microsoft article

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallback);
        schemaSet.Add("http://tempuri.org/customer.xsd", "customer.xsd");
        schemaSet.Compile();

        XmlSchema xmlSchema = null;
        foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas())
        {
            xmlSchema = schema;
        }
// Following 2 lines can be removed, as there is no use and may cause errors
   //         DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
     //       myDS.ReadXmlSchema("customer.xsd");

        foreach (object item in xmlSchema.Items)
        {
            XmlSchemaElement schemaElement = item as XmlSchemaElement;
            XmlSchemaComplexType complexType = item as XmlSchemaComplexType;

            if (schemaElement != null)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Schema Element: {0}", schemaElement.Name);

                XmlSchemaType schemaType = schemaElement.SchemaType;
                XmlSchemaComplexType schemaComplexType = schemaType as XmlSchemaComplexType;

                if (schemaComplexType != null)
                {
                    XmlSchemaParticle particle = schemaComplexType.Particle;
                    XmlSchemaSequence sequence = particle as XmlSchemaSequence;

                    if (sequence != null)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlSchemaElement childElement in sequence.Items)
                        {
                            Console.Out.WriteLine("    Element/Type: {0}:{1}", childElement.Name,
                                                  childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name);
                        }

                    }
                    if (schemaComplexType.AttributeUses.Count > 0)
                    {
                        IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = schemaComplexType.AttributeUses.GetEnumerator();

                        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                        {
                            XmlSchemaAttribute attribute = (XmlSchemaAttribute)enumerator.Value;

                            Console.Out.WriteLine("      Attribute/Type: {0}", attribute.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (complexType != null)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Complex Type: {0}", complexType.Name);
                OutputElements(complexType.Particle);
                if (complexType.AttributeUses.Count > 0)
                {
                    IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = complexType.AttributeUses.GetEnumerator();

                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        XmlSchemaAttribute attribute = (XmlSchemaAttribute)enumerator.Value;
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("      Attribute/Type: {0}", attribute.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.Out.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.Out.WriteLine();
        Console.In.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OutputElements(XmlSchemaParticle particle)
    {
        XmlSchemaSequence sequence = particle as XmlSchemaSequence;
        XmlSchemaChoice choice = particle as XmlSchemaChoice;
        XmlSchemaAll all = particle as XmlSchemaAll;

        if (sequence != null)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("  Sequence");

            for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                XmlSchemaElement childElement = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
                XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
                XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
                XmlSchemaAll innerAll = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;

                if (childElement != null)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("    Element/Type: {0}:{1}", childElement.Name,
                                          childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name);
                }
                else OutputElements(sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle);
            }
        }
        else if (choice != null)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("  Choice");
            for (int i = 0; i < choice.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                XmlSchemaElement childElement = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
                XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
                XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
                XmlSchemaAll innerAll = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;

                if (childElement != null)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("    Element/Type: {0}:{1}", childElement.Name,
                                          childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name);
                }
                else OutputElements(choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle);
            }

            Console.Out.WriteLine();
        }
        else if (all != null)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("  All");
            for (int i = 0; i < all.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                XmlSchemaElement childElement = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
                XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
                XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
                XmlSchemaAll innerAll = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;

                if (childElement != null)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("    Element/Type: {0}:{1}", childElement.Name,
                                          childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name);
                }
                else OutputElements(all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle);
            }
            Console.Out.WriteLine();
        }

    }

    static void ValidationCallback(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            Console.Write("WARNING: ");
        else if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
            Console.Write("ERROR: ");

        Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
    }
```

And xsd that I have used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="customer"
targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/customer.xsd"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/customer.xsd"
xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/customer.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
   <xs:element name="Version">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Min" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:element name="Max" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="File">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Min" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:element name="Max" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Your code works fine, but not with my complete schema. I get this error: DataSet doesn't support 'union' or 'list' as simpleType. I will edit my question with the whole xsd

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I've changed the xsd file without using list

Comment: @Stampy okay will work on that issue will inform you soon. till then if my answer helps you to solve your problem then would you please mark this as answer.

Comment: Actually the above code works perfectly, just remove Dataset part, that is no use. That causes error.   DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
            //myDS.ReadXmlSchema("customer.xsd");