# Traversing an XSD in C# not finding all elements

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm working on a solution that posts data to a SOAP web service. My sending application has a database table that holds the mappings between that application and the receiving application.

I've generated a class from the XSD using xsd tools. Ideally the solution will then traverse the elements within the xsd/class and if the element name sits in my database table, it will set that elements property accordingly.

First I found this documentation from Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/traversing-xml-schemas

But it only finds one level of parent and child

Then I kept digging and found this post on here

[Traversing XML Schemas failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828045/traversing-xml-schemas-failed)

This gives me the same result, so I can only assume its the schema that is the problem?

This is what is looks like, I can't get to "Type" for example

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqbt9.jpg)

Comment: If you have the URL for the SOAP web service, Visual Studio will scaffold the proxy classes you need to call the service methods. You do not need to go down the `xsd.exe` path. I will find a technical article to share.

Comment: Here's an article from MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx

Comment: Thanks for posting. The API doesn't provide a WSDL. If I add a service reference I get "The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information."

Comment: What is the XSD for then?

Comment: Are there types defined in the xsd to make calls to the service? `ServiceClient` (?)

Comment: No, nothing like that, just the class that contains the elements etc.

Comment: You have a datable which is a flat object with rows and columns.  Then you say "But it only finds one level of parent and child"  A datatable is only one level so how do you expect to have multiple levels?